# Azure functions proxies Invalid URI: noSlash

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I am trying to use an Azure function proxy to allow CORS on an API which I don't have access to the server for.

I have followed the steps in [this article](https://medium.com/@Sneezry/use-azure-functions-proxies-to-solve-cors-issues-572916535fca)

I have the route template as `/qless/{*rest}` and the backend URL as `https://merchant.us1.qless.com/qless/api/v1/{rest}` however the response I recieve is:
`400 (Invalid URI: noSlash)`.

If I change to use the Github API (as they do in the article), it works fine.

I have ensured that localhost (where I am sending request from) is listed in the functions' CORS settings.

The full request that I send is: `https://XXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/qless/kiosk/location/XXXXXXXX/queues/` so I don't see where the additional slash is coming from (like the response suggests). I have tried removing trailing and intermediate slashes. Thanks for your assistance.

**Edit**

By sending a `Proxy-Trace-Enabled` header I have realised that the function is rewriting `/` as `%2F` - how can I prevent this?

```
      {
        "source": "rewrite-uri",
        "timestamp": "2020-02-27T05:04:28.8777839Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:00.2596935",
        "data": {
          "message": "Updated request URL per specified rewrite template.",
          "request": {
            "url": "https://merchant.us1.qless.com/qless/api/v1/kiosk%2Flocations%2FXXXXXXXXXX/"
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution [in this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3350)

Set `AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_BACKEND_URL_DECODE_SLASHES` as an application setting to `true` (defaults to false) which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_function_proxy_backend_url_decode_slashes)